# Reverting trasnferred calls or tracing back transferred numbers?

Tags: twilio

So I would like to do something where if I make a outbound call to say, a service representative. Then, that person transfers me to a department A, and department A transfers me to department B, then is there a way to get connected to department A instead of calling the service representative again to reach department A?

Is this even possible with twilio api?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify which side of this scenario you want to build.  You want to create an IVR that tracks the call "history" of an incoming caller, or you want to create an app that that will make an outbound call to an IVR and track call transfers?

Comment: Outbound call and track call transfers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Unfortunately I don't believe there really is any way to do this.  Its likely that both RepA and RepB are connected to a local PBX inside their own org, so the fact that a "transfer" happens is not even something that occurs on the public switch telephone network so even the carriers don't know that a transfer has happened.

That means their is no data we can track, even if we wanted to.

Hope that helps.